# Details about JQuery's .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the description of the .html() method: "Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements." My question is what exactly is the "HTML contents" it refers to?

Lets say I have a div with content I wish to store HTML content for but also render it raw for viewing purposes. Lets say e is my Div.

```
 $(e).html() //this returns a string with what looks like regular HTML besides the occurrence of many HTML entities.
//if i search for greater than signs:
x.text().search("&gt") //I get 2273 which I'm assuming is the number of occurrences.
//However if I convert the HTML to a string I seem to get different content. Why?
$(output).val(e.html().toString()); //for viewing the output markup for a div
e.html().toString().search("&gt") //this now gives me 317, which is a lot less HTML entities than I had before
```

Would I be correct in saying that the .toString() method just corrupts my HTML content? Which one do I want? Whenever I render this to a raw div I get similar results for both even though they seem vastly different. Which one do I want in order to display and save the correct output information? Any knowledge is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`&gt` will match both `&gt;` and `>` so when you run it on an html string will match all the tags as well as uses of `&gt;` in text

Hard to tell what you are comparing since you use unknown `x.text()`

Comment: Is this: "&gt will match both &gt; and >" just something about the .search() method I don't know about?